# Magento 2 create invoice for igst rest api

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api

I am trying to add IGST and SGST and CGST in invoice rest api , please help me ,in Magento2.

Comment: What are your tax rate details for your products ?

Comment: Have you created the GST tax rates and rules ?